# Emulator do not display as of in device

Tags: android-layout, android-emulator

I have device whose resolution is 1024*720. I am using same resolution in emulator while creating my emulator, but still emulator do not display properly as of in device. Emulator cut UI part from right but same  app will run properly in device without any problem of UI. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set your UI layout as [linear layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html). I think it will help you.

Comment: sorry  i can't ,not possible to show and the problem is emulator settings not done correctly so that it show same display as device